# When integrating by part produces a singularity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integration, operator-theory, integral-operators

I'm currently interesting in the following operator:
$$O[f](x):=f(x)-2xe^{x^2}\int_x^{+\infty}dt \, e^{-t^2} f(t)$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ smooth and decaying at infinity fast enough with the homogeneous condition that $\int_\mathbb{R} f(t)e^{-t^2} \, dt=0$

I would like to present $O$ as an integral operator and so would like to get rid of the first term by integrating by part:

\begin{align}
& {-2}xe^{x^2} \int_x^{+\infty} dt \, e^{-t^2} f(t) \\[8pt]
= {} & 2xe^{x^2} \left[e^{-t^2}\dfrac{f(t)}{2t} \right]_x^{+\infty} - 2xe^{x^2} \int_x^{+\infty} dt \, e^{-t^2} \left(-\frac{f(t)}{2t^2} + \dfrac{f'(t)}{2t}\right)
\end{align}

which leads to the following expression:

$$O[f](x)=-2xe^{x^2}\int_x^{+\infty} dt \, e^{-t^2} \left(-\frac{f(t)}{2t^2}+\frac{f'(t)}{2t}\right).$$

This identity remains valid for $x>0$ but I'm wondering if it would be possible to extend this identity till $(-\infty, 0)$ by making appear a Cauchy principal value/finite part integral.

Comment: why not $O[f](x):=-\int_{x}^{+\infty}dt\bigl(f'(t)+2xe^{x^2}e^{-t^2}f(t)\bigr).$

Comment: Thaanks! That's actually a good idea. Though my goal is to obtain a control $\|O[f]\|_\infty\leq C\|f\|_{H^1(\mathbb{R})}$ where $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ is the 1st usual Sobolev space, so I'd have to write $$-f(x)=e^{x^2}\int_{x}^{+\infty}dte^{-t^2}(f'(t)-2tf(t))dt$$ and this is nice. Nonetheless I'm still interesting in my original question. How would it be possible to extend this formula to the negative semi-axis ?

Comment: your formula has a $1/t^2$ singularity, which cannot be regularised as as principal value.

Comment: For $f$ smooth near $0$, say with two continuous derivatives, and $f(0) = 0$, 
$$ -\frac{f(t)}{2t^2} + \frac{f’(t)}{2t} = - \frac{f’’(0)}{4} + o(1) , $$
so your second expression of $O[f]$ makes sense. For general $f$ you could then consider $O[f - f(0)]$.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker Even with Hadamard regularization ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_regularization

Comment: @ThomasLehéricy that's actually a very good point! Thank you very much. Would you have an idea about how to extend this formula for general $x<0$ without assuming $f(0)=0$ ?

Comment: I first thought to compute $O[1]$, then extend $O$ on the set of functions of the form $f + c$ where $f(0)=0$... But realized that $1$ is not a valid function. What you can do instead is fix a valid function $h$ with $h(0)=1$, any function really, and write $O[f] = O[f-f(0)h] + O[h]$. The first is computed with your integral, the second is tabulated.

Also, to obtain a similar formula for $x<0$, use that $\int_x^\infty f(t) e^{-t^2} dt = - \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) e^{-t^2} dt$, and do the same integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: you might require that $\int_{[1,\infty)} \frac{|f’(t)|}{t} e^{t^2} dt < \infty$, and the same on $(-\infty,1]$, otherwise your formula may fail to be defined. I am making this assumption now.**

Let us write $\mu = e^{-t^2} dt$. For every $f\in L^1(\mu)$ with $\int f d\mu = 0$,
$$ O[f](x) = f(x) + 2xe^{x^2} \int_{-\infty}^x fd\mu $$
so that for every $x<0$, by your same integration by parts
$$ O[f](x) = 2xe^{x^2} \int_{-\infty}^x \left(\frac{-f(t)}{2t^2} + \frac{f’(t)}{2t}\right)d\mu(t) .  \qquad (*) $$
If $f(0)=0$, we can see that $\frac{-f(t)}{2t^2} + \frac{f’(t)}{2t} = -f’’(0)/4 + o(1)$ for $t\to 0$, which is integrable near 0, thus the integrals above can be made sense of for every $x\in\mathbb R$.
Furthermore, we can compute the value of the integral for $x\to 0$: for $x>0$
$$ \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{-f(t)}{2t^2} + \frac{f’(t)}{2t}\right)d\mu(t) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{O[f](x)}{-2xe^{x^2}} = \frac{-f’(0)}{2} + \int_0^\infty fd\mu , $$
and for $x<0$
$$ \int_{-\infty}^0 \left(\frac{-f(t)}{2t^2} + \frac{f’(t)}{2t}\right)d\mu(t) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{O[f](x)}{2xe^{x^2}} = \frac{f’(0)}{2} - \int_{0}^\infty fd\mu , $$
which means
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{-f(t)}{2t^2} + \frac{f’(t)}{2t}\right)d\mu(t) = 0 . $$
This allows us to conclude that your formula and $(*)$ coincide on every $x\in \mathbb R$, thus that either of them can be extended to $\mathbb R$. This only hold for $f(0)=0$ though! To extend it to general $f$, fix an arbitrary $h\in L^1(\mu)$ with $h(0)=1$ and $\int hd\mu = 0$, and write
$$ O[f] = O[f-f(0)h] + f(0) O[h] $$
with the tabulated $O[h]$ computed by the original definition and $O[f-f(0)h]$ by the "integral operator" form $(*)$.

Comment: That is very very nice! The thing is, I kind of simplified the problem here to make it more accessible to your (very helpful) suggestions. Though in fact the measure $\mu$ I'm dealing with is a bit more complicated than the Gaussian, hence it doesn't seem really realistic to have a "tabulated" function in my case. But I guess you solve the case for all $x\neq0$.

Comment: For $x=0$, one has to use the fact that $\int_x^{\infty}dt e^{-t^2}(\dfrac{1}{t}+\dfrac{1}{t^2})=O(x^{-1})$. Hence this divergence at $0$ is compensated by the $x$ that multiplies the integral!